# Vue Router Gaurd Not Working When Page Refreshes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to protect some pages with a router guard. When a user visits, they should be asked to login when they try to access these pages. It works while I am in the app, but when the user refreshes the page, or just simply copies the URL and paste it on a browser and is also logged in there, the user should get these pages still. But this is not the case right now. It throws this error: [vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation: I need the user to be redirected to the login page if they try to access a guarded page, and also give them this page if they are logged in.

```
beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    if (!store.state.isUserLoggedIn) {
    next({
    path: '/login', // back to safety
    query: {
    redirectFrom: to.fullPath
    }
    })
    // }else if(!localStorage.getItem('userLoggedIn')){
    // next()
     } else {
    next()
```

Answer (score 1):

The best practice and what you should do here is to use [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards).

index.js (router file)

```
const ifNotAuthenticated = (to, from, next) => {
    if (!store.state. isUserLoggedIn) {
        next();
        return;
    }
    next("/");
};

const ifAuthenticated = (to, from, next) => {
    if (store.state. isUserLoggedIn) {
        next();
        return;
    }
    next("/login");
};

const routes =[
    {
        path: "/home",
        name: "Home",
        component: Home,
        beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated,
      },
    {
        path: "/login",
        name: "Login",
        component: Login,
        beforeEnter: ifNotAuthenticated,
      }
]
```

`beforeEnter` here is the key to know whether an authenticated user should proceed to the next page or go to login.

Comment: Still the same problem. If a user is logged in, and the user refreshes the page, the page is not displayed. This is my issue. It's expected that the user might sometimes trigger a refresh, or come from an external source. I would also like the user to be able to view these pages still if they are still logged in.

Answer (score 0):

After carefully studying the errors I was getting, I was able to realize that the router guard was not seeing even the persistent Vuex state when the page is refreshed, or a user navigates to the URL directly. So I decided to switch the variable that the router guard analyzes to see if a user is logged in to a localStorage variable. Even then, I was having issues when it was a boolean variable. I changed it to an int, 1 for the logged-in state, and 0 for the logged-out state. This works flawlessly. Just in case anyone is having this issue.